# WebView no carga url

Tags: android, android-studio, webview-android

HICE una pequeña investigación la talvez posible solución esta al final, espero puedan leerla toda, el problema es demasiado simple al parecer sin embargo, me ha quitado muchos días intentando encontrar una solución.

Estoy terminando un proyecto pero la implementación del onBackPressed(), sea ah vuelvo demasiado complicada. Entonces decidí implementar mi propio sistema para la tecla de retroceder, Logre que funcione perfectamente sin embargo haciendo distintas pruebas me encontré con un error

Pensaba que era un error de mi implementación, por ello cree un proyecto de cero para descartar cualquier  error y me di con la sorpresa de que el error que se produce es muy interesante.

El proyecto consta de la plantilla de actividad "Bottom Navigation Activity" que ofrece android al crear un proyecto nuevo. Es decir que el la actividad consta de un bottom navigation que cambia los fragmentos y gestiona la navegación usando Navegación Components, hasta ahí es como cualquier proyecto normal,lo único que he realizado es agregar un webview a uno de los 3 fragmentos que se crean por defecto.

```
class DashboardFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_dashboard) {

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        OneWeb.webChromeClient = object : WebChromeClient(){
        }

        OneWeb.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
        }

        val setting: WebSettings = OneWeb.settings
        setting.javaScriptEnabled = true
        OneWeb.loadUrl("https://google.com")

        but.setOnClickListener {   //también agregue este botón, lo explico mas adelante
            OneWeb.loadUrl("https://kotlinlang.org/")
            Toast.makeText(activity, "atras", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

    }

}
```

En la actividad agregue que la url se cargue cuando se presiona el botón retroceder.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        OneWeb.loadUrl("https://kotlinlang.org/")
        Toast.makeText(this,"atras", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
```

**ERROR**
Pasa que al presiona la tecla de retroceso la pagina que se debería cargar no se carga, si se ah presionado la tecla retroceso antes y se ha regresado luego de haber salido del fragmento.
Es decir simplemente que la tecla de atrás que debería cargar la pagina indicada (KotlinLand) cuando se presiona, no carga dicha pagina, claro esto pasa después de  que se halla presionado ya una vez, y haber regresado luego de salir del fragmento donde se encuentra el webview.

Para entenderlo mejor esta es lo que pasa:*"recordar que uso bottomNavigation, la navegación es automática con navegación components"*

RUTA

inicia en home -->   ** Voy al fragmento donde esta el webview, se carga la pagina inical(google)**  -->  presiono tecla de atras, se carga la pagina(KotlinLand) -->    **salgo del fragmento a cualquiera de los dos otros** -->  ingreso nuevamentte al fragmento, se carga la pagina inicial (google) hasta ahi todo va bien"  -->  **presiono tecla de atrás YA NO  carga la pagina(KotlinLand), sin embargo al parecer si se ejecuta onbackpreseed por que el toast si se muestra.**

Otro caso
inicia en home -->   **voy al fragmento donde esta el webview, se carga la pagina inical(google)**  -->  NO presiono tecla de atras-->    **salgo del fragmento a cualquiera de los dos otros**, "hasta aqui no se ha  presiono la tacle de retroceso, simplemente se ingreso y salio del fragmento con los botones del BottomNavigation" -->  ingreso nuevamente al fragmento, se carga la pagina inicial (google)   -->  **presiono tecla de atrás Si carga la pagina(KotlinLand) y se el toast si se muestra.**   "hasta aqui todo PARECE NORMAL SIN EMBARGO si se vuelve a cambiar del fragmento  y se vuelve a ingresar YA NO se carga la pagina al retroceder, es decir el problema aparece nuevamente , es como si EL ONBACKPRESED SOLO TUVIRA DOS OPORTUNIDAS PARA FUNCIONAR, SI SE SALE DEL FRAGMENTO CLARO, YA QUE SINO, OSEA SE MANTIENE EN EL FRAGMENTO DESDE EL INICO, SI SE REALIZA CORRECTAMENTE LA CARGA DE LA URL INDICADA(KOTLINLAND), cuando se presiona la tecla de retroceso"

El toast siempre se muestra correctamente sea cual sea el caso siempre que se deba mostrar se muestra, el problema es con la carga de el webview.

DATO CURIOSO
Un hecho que me parece relevante es que en mi proyecto original tenia un onPageStarted dentro de mi webViewClient, aqui realizo la comprobación que se muestra en el código de abajo, lo que pasaba aquí es me surgía un error en la linea que marco, cosa que no tendría sentido ya que supuestamente para que se corra dicha linea, la url debe ser diferente de null, recordar que esto solo ocurre cuando ingreso nuevamente al fragmento y deseo utilizar el botón de atrás por segunda vez para que se cargue la pagina .

```
override fun  onPageStarted(view: WebView?, url: String?, favicon: Bitmap?) {

            if (url == null){
                Toast.makeText(activity, "url ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            }else{
                Toast.makeText(activity, url, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() //***error objeto null*** 
            }
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon)

        }
```

ERROR DADO SI COLOCO PARA QUE SE MUESTRE LA URL EN UN TOAST

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.space.victory, PID: 1866
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
        at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:204)
        at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:605)
        at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:574)
        at com.space.victory.ui.One.OneFragment$onViewCreated$2.onPageStarted(OneFragment.kt:37)
        at Z80.c(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-432415233:2)
        at j6.handleMessage(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-432415233:160)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8107)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
```

Cabe recalcar que no existe mas código, ninguna configuración adicional que provoque algún error.

OTRO DATO

Adicional ha eso coloque un botón en el fragmento del webview que tiene el mismo código del onbackpreseed, en este caso este si funciona correctamente es decir al presionar el botón **que agrege** luego de hacer salido del fragmento y ingresado nuevamente al mismo que contiene el webview, si realiza su función de cargar la pagina que se indica y siguien funcionando corretamente apesar de cualquier cambio, sin embargo el botón de retroceso no lo hace, el toast si se muestra con el texto "atras" es decir si se ejecuta el onbackpressed, pero la pagina que se indica  no se carga.

**TALVEZ POSIBLE SOLUCION**

Lo que he entendido despues de buscar diferente información y creo que podría ser una pista proviene de las siguientes preguntas,[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22480531/android-webview-onpagestarted-onpagefinished-shouldoverrideurlloading-not-g], [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34887331/attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-java-lang-string-android-content-context-getpa], [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59834398/android-navigation-component-back-button-not-working],lo que puedo entender es que se trata de que se crea una nueva instancia o se sobreescribe algo, ya que dado que el toast si se muestra me hace pensar que es un problema solo del webview, talvez se este duplicando y no se este cargando la url que se indica, sin embargo no tengo idea de como podría implementarlo a mi proyecto, talvez no tengan mucha relaciona con mi proyecto sin embargo creo que puede ser una idea de los que sucede al cambiar de fragmento ya que como dije si no se cambia la tecla sigue funcionando correctamente.

Ojala tengan ideas de que puede estar pasando me parece algo muy simple y que no se realice correctamente ha detenido todo mi proyecto, podria tratarse de un error de android que escapa de nuestras manos o tal
vez necesito implementar algo mas para que funcione de forma correcta, ojala me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Primer error

> Cabe recalcar que no existe mas código, ninguna configuración adicional que provoque algún error.

Es gracioso que digas eso cuando el error se debe precisamente a una configuración adicional. Especificamente a este plugin:

```
// build.gradle (app)
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'  <-- este es el culpable
}
```

Cito la documentación:

> Kotlin Android Extensions is deprecated, which means that using Kotlin synthetics for view binding is no longer supported.

Verás que reemplazando el `OneWeb` por un `findViewById()`, la aplicación funcionará como esperas.

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    findViewById<WebView>(R.id.oneWeb)?.loadUrl("https://kotlinlang.org/")
    Toast.makeText(this,"atras", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

Eso funcionará pero tampoco es la mejor forma de hacerlo. Lo ideal sería que elimines el plugin y migres a View Binding. A partir de la proxima versión de android studio, las plantillas ya vendrán con una implementación de view binding pero por ahora lee la [guia para hacer la migración](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding/migration)

### Segundo error

> me surgía un error en la linea que marco, cosa que no tendría sentido ya que supuestamente para que se corra dicha linea, la url debe ser diferente de null

El mensaje dice que el error se produce en `Context.getPackageName()`. A esta altura ya debes saber que `Activity` es una subclase de `Context`. Esto significa que `activity` era nulo cuando lo pasaste como argumento a `Toast.makeText(activity, url, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()`

### Causa

Dije que el primer error era culpa del plugin pero eso no es del todo cierto. La verdadera causa de estos dos errores (y de uno más que te faltó ver) es que tienes una referencia que apunta a un objeto que ya no existe. Esto se conoce como *memory leak*.

El **tercer error** es que tu app tambíen crashea si presionas el back button antes de navegar por primera vez al fragment del webview.

Para entender la causa primero debes entender que sucede cuando navegas y también que hace ese plugin que debes eliminar. Pon atención porque voy a darte una clase gratis.

Cuando navegas a un fragment, se crea una instancia de él y se infla su respectivo layout (xml). Todos estos objetos se almacenan en la memoria ram y se liberan una vez que el fragment completa su ciclo de vida (por ejemplo cuando navegas a otro fragmento). Sin embargo, hay condición para que esto se cumpla y es que no haya ninguna referencia apuntando a ellos. Si creas un fragment y lo almacenas en una variable, este siempre va a estar en memoria independientemente de si está siendo usado por una activity o no.

El plugin "kotlin-android-extensions", específicamente su feature "Kotlin synthetics", es lo que permite que puedas acceder desde tu código a los elementos del layout a través de su id. Internamente hace algo muy similar a esto:

```
// si quieres pruebalo en tu app y obtendrás el mismo resultado
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    val OneWeb by lazy { findViewById<WebView>(R.id.OneWeb) }
    
    ...

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        OneWeb.loadUrl("https://kotlinlang.org/")
    }

}
```

Habiendo entendido eso, es muy fácil explicar el comportamiento de tu app.

**Por qué no se carga la página?**

Aunque usted no lo crea, la página SI SE ESTÁ CARGANDO. El problema es que la webView en la que se carga no es la misma que estás viendo. En ese momento hay dos `DashboardFragment` en memoria: el que es visible y el que no pudo ser eliminado porque tienes una referencia apuntando a él. Esto significa que, además de los problemas mencionados, estás desperdiciando memoria en el dispositivo. Por eso lo llaman *memory leak*.

**Cómo se explica lo siguente?**

> es como si EL ONBACKPRESED SOLO TUVIRA DOS OPORTUNIDAS PARA FUNCIONAR, SI SE SALE DEL FRAGMENTO

Esto simplemente es el funcionamiento del plugin. Crea la referencia la primera vez que lees `OneWeb` en la MainActivity. Si no se ejecuta el `onBackPressed()`, no va a haber ningun pointer apuntando a la webview y por lo tanto, el fragment va a poder descansar en paz.

**Por qué se produce la `NullPointerException` en `onPageStarted`?**

Este error es una concecuencia del primero y una prueba de que la página si está cargando. Lo que ocurré es que `activity` retorna la Activity a la que está asociado el fragment. Naturalmente un fragment que sólo existe gracias a tus errores no está asociado a ninguna activity.

**Por qué crashea si se presiona el back button antes de navegar al `DashboardFragment`?**

Ovbiamente esto es otra NPE (NullPointerException) que sucede porque `OneWeb` aún no existe. Para solucionar este ni siquiera tienes que dejar de usar el plugin, todo lo que necistas es hacer una safe call (`?.`). Quedaría así: `OneWeb?.loadUrl("https://kotlinlang.org/")`

### Solución

La solución que te di antes funciona pero no es bueno usar `findViewById` porque hace que tu app sea mas lenta. Esta es una solución usando jetpack view binding:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var oneWeb: WebView? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {...}

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        oneWeb?.loadUrl("https://kotlinlang.org/")
    }

}
```

Así debería quedar tu fragment después de migrar a viewBinding. Lo más importante acá es asignarle el valor `null` a la variable que tienes en la MainActivity justo antes de que se destruya el fragment. Para eso existe el método `onDestroyView()`.

```
class DashboardFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentDashboardBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentDashboardBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val mainActivity = requireActivity() as MainActivity
        mainActivity.oneWeb = binding.oneWeb
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {...}

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        val mainActivity = requireActivity() as MainActivity
        // esto previene memory leaks
        mainActivity.oneWeb = null
        _binding = null
    }

}
```

### Resumen de lo aprendido en esta clase

- Que es un memory leak y como evitarlo.
- Que hace el plugin 'kotlin-android-extensions' y porque no usarlo.
- Que alternativa hay para reemplazarlo.

**Repaso rápido por si quedó alguna duda**

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_dashboard.*  <-- plugin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onBackPressed() {
        OneWeb?.loadUrl()  <-- memory leak
    }
}
```

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    val OneWeb by lazy { findViewById<WebView>(R.id.OneWeb) }  <-- memory leak
    override fun onBackPressed() {
        OneWeb?.loadUrl()
    }
}
```

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onBackPressed() {
        findViewById<WebView>(R.id.OneWeb)?.loadUrl()  <-- NO memory leak
    }
}
```

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var oneWeb: WebView? = null
    override fun onBackPressed() {
        findViewById<WebView>(R.id.OneWeb)?.loadUrl()
    }
}
class DashboardFragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView() {
        (requireActivity() as MainActivity).oneWeb = oneWeb  <-- memory leak
    }
}
```

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var oneWeb: WebView? = null
    override fun onBackPressed() {
        findViewById<WebView>(R.id.OneWeb)?.loadUrl()
    }
}
class DashboardFragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView() {
        (requireActivity() as MainActivity).oneWeb = oneWeb
    }
    override fun onDestroyView() {
        (requireActivity() as MainActivity).oneWeb = null  <-- NO memory leak
    }
}
```

### Bonus

- No le des nombres que empiecen con mayúscula a variable o a los id de las views. Esto puede causar un mal entendido a la hora de leer tu codigo porque los nombres que empiezan con mayúscula deben estar reservados para las clases.
  Por convención, los resources id se nombran usando un `_` para separar las palabras. Es decir que el id de tu webView debería ser `one_web`, pero `oneWeb` también es aceptable.
- No uses toast para hacer debugs. Para eso existe la clase `Log`. En vez de esto `Toast.makeText(this, "atras", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()` usa `Log.d("MainActivity", "atras")`. Por convención, se pasa como primer argumento el nombre de la clase que imprime el mensaje pero puedes pasarle lo que quieras.

Comment: Gracias, funciona y sobre todo puede entender el problema, realmente me parecía algo muy inusual lo que pasaba, anote todas sus recomendaciones.
Sabia que no era recomendable usar los sintéticos de kotlin, pero no pensé que usándolos podía generar algún error que se provoque exclusivamente por no saber como funcionan por detrás.
Seguiré sus recomendaciones y los bonus acerca del toast y los nombres de los id. Los sintéticos me parecían muy eficientes, ya que los podía usar de forma rápida sin embargo gracias a sus consejos tratare de migrar a  ViewBinding .
Nuevamente le agradezco por todo

Comment: La única duda que me quedo es acerca de esto

" El mensaje dice que el error se produce en Context.getPackageName().........."

Por que activity era nulo en ese momento

Comment: todo empieza en esta línea `makeText(activity, url, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)`. La NPE no es porque `url` sea nulo sino porque `activity` (el primer argumento) es nulo. Esa es la conclusión a la que deberías llegar viendo el mensaje y siguiendo el stack trace. Entender los mensajes de error es una habilidad importante que también debes aprender.

Comment: el porqué lo expliqué mas abajo en la parte de preguntas

Comment: Si te sirvió la respuesta, marcala como correcta y borra el otro post que hiciste con la misma pregunta.