# Mostrar y ocultar fragmento respuesta inesperada

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragment

Necesitaba mostrar y ocultar un fragmento al hacer click en un botón, entonces mi código quedo así.

```
val fragment = DashboardFragment()

fun showFg() {
    if (show) { //si esta creado, lo remuevo
        val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        transaction.remove(fragment)
        transaction.commit()
        show = false
    } else { //lo creo, si no esta creado
        val fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
        val fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        fragmentTransaction.add(
            R.id.fragment_container,
            fragment
        )//con replace, el resultado es el mismo
        fragmentTransaction.commit()
        show = true
    }
}
```

Funcionaba bien y no notaba nada extraño hasta que tuve que utilizar una variable y resulto que al salir y volver a ingresar al fragment es decir presiona el botón que llama a `showFg()`, el valor de la variable se mantenía. Por ejemplo al inicio si la variable finaliza con valor `2` por el `+=1` , luego cuando volvía a ingresar esperaba un `2` sin embargo me aparecía un `3` y el valor iba incrementando cada vez que ingresaba al fragment. La variable nunca volvía a su valor original.

```
    class DashboardFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_dashboard) {

    var num = 1  //variable que mantiene su valor

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        num += 1
        Log.i("testfragment", num.toString())  //se espera un 2 cada vez que ingrese pero el valor se incrementaba por que la variable empezaba con el ultimo valor asignado
    }

}
```

Nota: Si se crea la variable dentro de onViewCreated, si se comporta como debería.
He tratado de encontrar una solución o al menos entender el problema y he llegado a la conclusión de que estoy cometiendo un error en la transacción del fragmento, ya que he realizo una prueba usando navigation component y he tenido el resultado esperado, sin embargo esto no resuelve mi problema ya que deseo mostrar y ocultar el mismo fragmento y no logro hacerlo de esta forma.

He visto ejemplos donde se usa show y hide, al parecer ese es el camino. Sin embargo me gustaría entender por que ocurre el problema descrito anteriormente.

Comment: por qué no usas el navigation component? Sería bueno que también explicaras cuál es tu caso de uso para poder darte soluciones alternativas.

Comment: solo necesito que el fragment se muestre y oculte cuando se hace click a un botón, no requiero navegación, sin embargo también intente usar navigation component pero no puedo hacer que se muestre y oculte el fragment, como podria hacer algo como eso con navigation component.

Comment: Sin embargo lo que mas me interesa es entender, que puede estar pasando, ya que cuando se destruye el fragment se llama correctamente a ondestroy y onpause, asi que no puedo entender por que la variable se mantiene con el ultimo valor asignado.

Comment: no agregues la etiqueta `android-studio` a menos que la pregunta esté relacionada con android studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que ya te expliqué esto una vez, un objeto nunca se va a eliminar mientras mantengas una referencia a él.

Este comentario en tu función está mal

```
if (show) {
    ...
} else { //lo creo, si no esta creado
```

Lo que hace es mostrar el fragment, no crearlo. El fragment lo creaste en el mismo momento en que creaste la activity y, como lo almacenaste en una de sus propiedades, va a existir hasta que la activity se cierre, por más que se llame su método onDestroy.

Esta es la línea que realmente creó el fragment

```
val fragment = DashboardFragment()
```

Sabiendo que la asignación inicial `var num = 1` se produce en el momento que se crea el fragment y que tu fragment se creó solamente una vez, debe quedarte muy claro por qué la variable nunca se reinicia.

Si modificas la función para que haga lo que está escrito en los comentarios, obtendrás el resultado esperado

> he realizo una prueba usando navigation component y he tenido el resultado esperado, sin embargo esto no resuelve mi problema ya que deseo mostrar y ocultar el mismo fragmento

El navigation component sí resuelve tu problema. Mostrar un fragment es lo mismo que navegar hacia él y ocultarlo es navegar al anterior. Todo lo que necesitas hacer es esto

```
fun showFg() {
    if (navController.currentDestination?.id == R.id.destination)
        //si esta creado, lo remuevo
        navController.popBackStack()
    else
        //lo creo, si no esta creado
        navController.navigate(R.id.destination)
}
```

Comment: Si entiendo ello, eso me funciona para las transacciones, pero desearía poder ocultar y mostrar el fragmento que inicia, y no funciona ya que navController.popBackStack()
no puede ir mas atrás. entonces el fragmento que inicia nunca se oculta.

Comment: Sin embargo lo que mas esperaba, era entender que estaba pasando, gracias a su  respuesta resolví ese problema.  

Ya que mi implementación inicial no ocasiona mayor inconveniente. Simplemente asignare la variable a su valor inicial en el onDestroy del fragmet.

Comment: Sí, eso va a funcionar pero va en contra de los [principios de navegión](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-principles) y también desperdicia memoria. No hay ninguna razón para hacer transacciones manualmente, el navigation component las reemplazó completamente. Si no te permite hacer algo, probablemente sea porque no deberías hacerlo.  Vuelve a leer la respuesta a tu [pregunta anterior](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/428722/webview-no-carga-url) y puedes agradecer con un voto positivo.

Comment: Tiene razón en esto " Si no te permite hacer algo, probablemente sea porque no deberías hacerlo", tratare de planificar mejor el sistema de navegación cuando empiece nuevos proyectos, también tomare en cuenta el desperdicio de memoria en toda mi app, gracias por recordarme que ya me había explicado esto en una pregunta anterior. Ahora todo quedo aun mas claro.